# Do Vietnamese citizens need a visa to enter Spain for short term?

Tags: visas, schengen, spain

I am new here.

I am studying in China (Beijing), and I have an opportunity to go to Spain (Valencia) for summer school in this July for one week. I have Vietnamese citizenship. I would like to ask some questions that:

1. Do I need to apply for a visa to enter Spain?
2. What kind of visa must I apply for?
3. How long does it take to get the visa?
4. How much does it cost?
5. What supporting documents must I provide?
6. Any suggestion for me when I travel to Spain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spain is a Schengen treaty country, so you will need a Schengen visa:

> Holders of a Vietnamese passport require a visa for the "Schengen
>   States".

http://eeas.europa.eu/delegations/vietnam/eu_travel/visa/index_en.htm

The cost for all temporary visas is 60 EUR, and you also need insurance and a lot of documentation.  If your summer school regularly takes in foreign visitors, they should already know what visa you need and how to apply for it, so talk to them first.